# Understanding the pricing related to Google Cloud Alerting based on Metric Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-alerts

We are trying to create a series of rolling 1-hour alerts in Google Cloud.

For example: Cloud Maps function API calls when exceeding a usage limit of (2500). This triggers an alert message to our backend system so someone from the technical team can review the same.

Question: It is not clearly understood, how much would this cost? We have added more than 10 alerts and all of them are using Metric Explorer for a rolling one-hour window.

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? Does it help to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pricing for Google Cloud Monitoring lets you control your usage and spending. You can use the free data usage allotments to get started with no upfront fees or commitments. For monitoring API calls, Free allotment per month is initial 1 million API calls included per billing account. Later, the price would be $0.01/1,000 API calls(Write API calls are free).

To get a better understanding of the potential cost, you can refer to the pricing [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#pricing_examples_samples) provided by Google Cloud. Also you can try the estimated price of resources according to your need in the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator-legacy?hl=en&direct=true) and check how to [Create budgets and set up spending alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) for more information.